# Слова, оканчивающиеся на "-ква"

Tags: лексика

Сколько существует слов, оканчивающихся на "-ква"?

Answer (score 2):

Нетривиальный вопрос. :) **Окончания** *-ква* в русском языке нет. А слов, **оканчивающихся** на *-ква,* Зализняк приводит 10: кваква, саква, антиква, локва, смоква, буква, тыква, клюква, брюква, кряква.

Answer (score 1):

Таких слов не существует, потому что -ква окончанием быть не может.Заканчиваться этим сочетанием букв слово, конечно, может, но это не окончание.

Comment: А никто об окончании тут и не говорил.

Comment: Вопрос изначально был сформулирован по-другому, отсюда и мой ответ))

Answer (score 1):

Ещё есть группа языков *ква*  и звукоподражательное слово *ква-ква*. Слово *аква* входит в названия многих компаний и товаров.

Answer (score 1):

А ещё Мос**ква** :-)